# Access DOM element inside a function (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing chrome extension but stuck in the middle. I am beginner to chrome extension.
I want to access DOM inside a function.
TestA.js is a file which is used by content_script.js

**Question Updated:**

**TestA.js**

```
var Encryption = {}

Encryption.encryp = async function(arg1, arg2){
 var keys = [];
 .....
 .....
 .....
 //want to access DOM here but error occures:  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

 document.getElementById("#test").innerHTML = "This is test"
 return keys;
}
```

But works well if access on top of the file:

```
document.getElementById("#test").innerHTML = "This is test"
var Encryption = {}

Encryption.encryp = async function(arg1, arg2){
 .....
 .....
 .....


}
```

Comment: There's no way of knowing unless we see `fetchlist`--perhaps that's modifying the DOM?

Comment: The only explanation is that the element does not exist when the code runs. Debug your code in the built-in devtools debugger: set a breakpoint, run the code, and inspect the state and DOM when it triggers.